# Find sine function based on given zeros

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Lets say we have a finite set of integers (all of them $\geq 1$, given in ascending order, *e.g.* $S=\{1,2,3,5,7\}$ ), which should be roots of a sine function. Is there a possibility to define such a sine function on a simple way?

By the way, is there any kind of online tool for this?

Thanks

Comment: $\sin(\pi x)=0$ for all integers $x$.

Comment: I mean JUST the given x in S should be roots, not all x in N

Comment: What is the allowable form for what you're calling a "sine function"?

Comment: I need some kind of general oscillating function, which has exactly the root at the given integers. Maybe "sine" is too concrete here.

Comment: If your function oscillates, it is periodic and thus have an infinite number of zeroes. If you only want the elements of $S$ to be the integer roots of your function, you can take $$ f(x)=\prod_{s\in S}\sin(x-s) $$ For any integer $x$, you have $$f(x)=0\iff\exists s\in S,\sin(x-s)=0\iff\exists s\in S,\exists n\in\mathbb{Z},x=s+n\pi\iff\exists s\in S,x=s\iff x\in S$$ because $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: You want to find a curve whose x-coordinates of intersections with a sine function are as you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you gave, try this function:
$$
f(x)=-\cos(2\pi x)+\Bigl((x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)\Bigr)^2+1
$$
To make it less "extreme" looking, try this variant:
$$
f(x)=-\cos(2\pi x)+\frac{g(x)^2}{100{\,\cdot\,}g(x)^2+1}+1
$$
where
$$
g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)
$$

Comment: pretty extreme to the y-values, but this is some type of function, i was looking for

Comment: I'll edit it to make it less extreme.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $\sin\left(\lfloor x-1 \rfloor \lfloor x-2 \rfloor \cdots \right)$ , where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function.

The given function has roots only at those particular integers, because sine is never $0$ at any integer except $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a periodic function that is not sinusoidal, try this.

We first define $y$ as $\left[\frac{x}{10\sqrt2} \right]\cdot10\sqrt2$ where $[m]$ is the fractional part of $n$. Note that $10\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Now define our function as

$$f(y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad y\in S \\
            1 & \quad \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now there are infinitely many roots of $f(y)$ (because any periodic function containing at least $1$ root will have infinitely many roots), but they are of the form $s+10\sqrt2n$, where $s\in S$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$. As $10\sqrt2$ is irrational, any multiple of it plus some integer will be irrational and non-integer. So the only roots where $x\in\mathbb N$ is in $S$.

This function is non-continuous though so it might not be what you are looking for.